# What does Using “MX Anywhere 2S” may affect Wi-Fi and Bluetooth connectivity mean in iPadOS?

Tags: ipad, wifi, bluetooth, mouse, ipados

On iPadOS 13.4, the Bluetooth mouse functionality is substantially improved. I have an Logitech MX anywhere that I purchased to test this, and I notice a warning that it may affect WiFi or Bluetooth.

> Using “MX Anywhere 2S” may affect Wi-Fi and Bluetooth connectivity

[image: Bluetooth warning - Using MX Anywhere 2S may affect Wi-Fi and Bluetooth connectivity]

I know that any Bluetooth device uses 2.4 GHz unmanaged spectrum, so interference is always possible, but I wonder if there’s something specific at issue here or if Apple has documented which mouse devices will not get this warning.

Is there an official explanation why this alert is present or a list of supported protocols, devices, driver upgrades to have the best WiFi and Bluetooth experience on iPads with Bluetooth mice connected?

Comment: Interesting.  I connected my MX Master 3 and did *not* see that message

Comment: Thanks @Allan and FWIW the mouse is amazing, three pairing identities with a physical button to switch, solid wheel to scroll, solid all around, tracks amazingly on all surfaces. I can’t tell any downside so far despite the “warning” it “may” affect things.

Comment: I still have my 2S (the thumb button broke) so I'll fix it and see if I can get the message to appear - at least it'll confirm it's something specific to that mouse (as Apple sees it anyway).   I loved my 2S and the only reason I went to the 3 is because the thumb button got stuck in the down position.

Comment: Does this message still pop up when you disconnect your Apple Pencil?

Answer (score 3):

Some mice, like the MX Anywhere, support both Bluetooth and wireless radio connectivity (this is the connection method where you usually have to use a small USB receiver). This wireless radio uses 2.4 GHz spectrum as well and may interfere with BT and/or 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. So if I connect the USB dongle to power (which I do not, it's probably still in the box) that may / will cause the interference? I'll open support case with Apple and with Logitech to confirm I'm set, but this sounds very likely to be the reason.

Comment: I have a keyboard case which *only* supports Bluetooth (no alternative wireless connection). Yet iPadOS 13.4 shows this message as well.